# Impossible to restore fragment

Tags: android

I can't restore my fragment !

I'm saving like :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(cameraFragment != null && cameraFragment.isAdded())
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(savedInstanceState, "cameraFrameLayout", cameraFragment);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and restoring in onCreate(savedInstanceState) :

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        cameraFragment = CameraFragment.newInstance();
    else
        cameraFragment = (CameraFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("cameraFrameLayout");
```

When I change the device orientation I can successfully see that the onSaveInstanceState in called with my fragment but on the onCreate I have a null instance...

Txs for help !

Comment: Have you called `setRetainInstance(true)` on your `CameraFragment`?

Comment: Same thing (I ve put setRetainInstance(true) on the onCreateView() of my fragment...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the saved fragment in onRestoreInstanceState

```
public void onRetoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
   cameraFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState,"cameraFrameLayout");
}
```

Also notice that **getFragment** is called to the **FragmentManager** instead if **findFragmentByTag**. Hope it helps!

Note: call super methods in onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState overrides

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment onCreate() method write `setRetainInstance(true);`

In the Activity that creates the fragment you should do something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, CameraFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

The `android.R.id.content` can be different in your case. This is where you want to load your fragment.